# How effectively download file by url and convert to org.springframework.core.io.Resource?

Tags: java, spring, io, nio, fileoutputstream

I have a link that opens a file. The file can be a pdf or an image. I need to load this file and then use it in a service like `org.springframework.core.io.Resource`.

My code downloads a file and saves it to the repository folder. But it strictly specifies the extension and file name.

```java
public org.springframework.core.io.Resource downloadWithJavaNIO(String fileURL, String localFilename) {
    URL url = new URL(fileURL);
    try (ReadableByteChannel readableByteChannel = Channels.newChannel(url.openStream());
         FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(localFilename);
         FileChannel fileChannel = fileOutputStream.getChannel()
    ) {
        fileChannel.transferFrom(readableByteChannel, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
    }

    // TODO converting to org.springframework.core.io.Resource
    return null;
}
```

Can I somehow automatically determine the extension and file name? `.pdf`/`.png` and so on. Is there any way to convert it to `org.springframework.core.io.Resource` without the stage of saving to the repository?

What would be the best way to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Spring does provide some Resource implementations.

try to us FileUrlResource and let us know it works or not.

```
Resource resource = new FileUrlResource(new URL(fileURL));
```